# How to scale arc corners to be equal?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, transform

I'm trying to duplicate and scale a rectangle I created with arc corners to create a series of thinner lines inside.  The problem is when I start scaling the lines the arcs don't equally line up with the larger outer arc.  I held shift+alt down to scale uniformly toward the center, didn't work.  I tried using the "Scale Stroke & Effects" option in the transform dialog but that didn't help.  Any idea how to do this without having to create this multiple times?

[image]

Comment: I think maybe the simplest thing would be to create a brush?

Comment: **How** did you "create a series of thinner lines inside"? Using the Appearance Panel and Offset Path effect should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I think @Scott is right, you should be able to just use a negative value for `Object > Path > Offset Path` and achieve the new inner paths. You may have to manually adjust the stroke weight though to achieve each iteration looking thinner.
[image: Object > Path > Offset Path]

Comment: I would use the Appearance panel with **one** object and not generate a multitude of separate paths with the Object menu. But that's me.

Comment: You teach me yet another thing! I didn't even know that was an option... thanks @Scott